# Sort While Loop or SQL Query by Looping Variable

Tags: php, sql, database, arrays, loops

I'm really stuck and have been searching for a while, but with no success.

Anyway, I have this formula known as the Bayesian Estimate: (WR) = (v ÷ (v+m)) × R + (m ÷ (v+m)) × C

And I have three database tables: persons, reviews, ratings.

The persons table is quite basic, but for the sake of this question, it only has one field: **ID**

The reviews table has **id, personID, description** where personID is the ID of the person.

The ratings table has **id, personID, reviewID, ratingX, ratingY, ratingZ** where person is the ID of the person and reviewID is the ID of the review.  ratingX/Y/Z are three different ratings for the person, and in my page shows the average of the three numbers.

**THE FORM THAT LISTS THEM**, however, sorts them by the Bayesian Estimate formula.  I do not know how to do this and it seems beyond me, since you cannot ORDER BY $bayesian_formula or anything like that.  The script looks something like this:

```
<?php
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM persons");
$m =; //SQL to get average number of reviews of all persons
$c =; //SQL to get average rating of all persons
while( $row = $result->fetch_array() ){

$r =; //SQL to get average ratings of person
$v =; //SQL to get total number of reviews of person

$formula = ($v / ($v+$m)) * $r + ($m / ($v+$m)) * $c;

$result2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ratings ORDER BY $formula");
    while( $row2 = $result2->fetch_array() ){

    $result3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id='$row2[person]'");
    $row3 = $result3->fetch_array();

    echo $row2['description']."<br> rating: ".round( ($row['ratingX'] + $row['ratingY'] + $row['ratingZ']) / 3 );

    }

}
?>
```

$formula loops to the database result's weighted rating each iteration.

Obviously that isn't correct.  How would I make this work?  Would I have to revise my entire script?  The actual one is much longer and detailed.

edit:

sqls are:

```
$c_query=$db->query("SELECT ((ratingX + ratingY + ratingZ) / 3) as avg_rate FROM ratings");
$c_ = $c_query->fetch_array();
$c = $c_['avg_rate'];

$m_query=$db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM ratings");
$m_ = $m_query->fetch_array();
$m = $m_['count'];

$v_query=$db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM ratings WHERE person='$row[id]'");
$v_ = $v_query->fetch_array();
$v = $v_['count'];

$r_query=$db->query("SELECT ((ratingX + ratingY + ratingZ) / 3) as avg_rate FROM ratings WHERE person='$row[id]'");
$r_ = $r_query->fetch_array();
$r = $r_['avg_rate'];
```

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, etc) are you using?

Comment: Can you include the SQL used to derive m, c, r and v? It would probably be simpler and more efficient to derive and sort the result within SQL, rather than looping through the datasets within php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: I don't understand...  I read it and how would you use it to order my query?  Would you please give an example?

Comment: you move everything from PHP to stored procedure and then just use `CALL your_procedure_name()` in PHP to get your calculated data ordered.

Comment: Just please give me an example of how it could AT LEAST potentially help me.  It's pretty much a function for SQL...  It's a completely new topic to me and that's what the definition says it is, so I don't see how it can help.  Is it a temporary value?  If so how the hell do I use it, because I try $db->query("CREATE..."); then $db->query("CALL..."); but that doesn't do anything, and if I use my PHPMYADMIN's sql launcher, it returns an error as well.  And yes, I have mysqli support.

Comment: You store the procedure once, then you call it. Search for tutorials and benefits.

Comment: You aren't helping me at all or giving me any guidelines.  I've been searching what they are for the past 8 hours and all it tells me is that it works exactly like a function.  Only benefit is that it performs the queries faster.  How at all does that help me?  I don't know if you know what I'm trying to do, but how the hell can I CALL a procedure, and that would all of a sudden sort my database query's WHILE LOOP by a variable?  I do not want to physically make a new field or table or anything, and if all the CALL is doing is giving me the rating then that is useless.

Comment: I cannot write things for you. I gave you the clue and link. Sorry, I'm not following you anymore.